# is there difference between the json.loads in python2.7 vs python3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

We are migrating from Python 2.7 to Python 3. We are seeing the `json.loads` is not returning the same response in Python 2.7 and Python 3.

Below is an example. As we can see the `json.loads` in both of the versions return different results. I wanted to check if there is a way to fix this and have the same response in Python 3 which is return from Python 2.7

```
Python 2.7
Input:
json.loads('{"a":"AC","b":"ac","name":"Upgrade","status":"active","dateCreated":"Mon, 22 Aug 2011 20:58:45 +0000","dateUpdated":"Fri, 12 Jul 2011 21:52:26 +0000","token":"bar","type":"Full"}')

Response
{u'a': u'AC', u'status': u'active', u'b': u'ac', u'name': u'Upgrade', u'dateCreated': u'Mon, 22 Aug 2011 20:58:45 +0000', u'token': u'bar', u'dateUpdated': u'Fri, 12 Jul 2011 21:52:26 +0000', u'type': u'Full'}

Python 3
Input:
json.loads(b'{"a":"AC","b":"ac","name":"Upgrade","status":"active","dateCreated":"Mon, 22 Aug 2011 20:58:45 +0000","dateUpdated":"Fri, 12 Jul 2011 21:52:26 +0000","token":"bar","type":"Full"}')

Response:
{'a': 'AC', 'b': 'ac', 'name': 'Upgrade', 'status': 'active', 'dateCreated': 'Mon, 22 Aug 2011 20:58:45 +0000', 'dateUpdated': 'Fri, 12 Jul 2011 21:52:26 +0000', 'token': 'bar', 'type': 'Full'}
```

Comment: Your input is different.

Comment: The responses are superficially the same, except that the keys are ordered differently (this shouldn't matter - does it?). Python 2's `u'strings'` (specifically, "strings encoded in unicode, as opposed to base ascii") are the same as python 3's normal strings, so that's not an actual difference between the two.

Comment: Except of the typical Python 2 / 3 differences I don't see anything obvious.

Comment: The result can be used the exact same way. What's the issue?

Comment: Those are the same result.

Comment: They are not the same result. Please check the position of the `status` in the response of both the version of python. The reason I am asking because a poorly written application is not converting the JSON output from the python2.7 into csv. Now since element order is different in the dict, csv order generated from the dict is also different, which is causing the issue now.

Comment: What Python 3 version are you using? In Python 3.7, keys of a dictionary are guaranteed to be in the order in which they were inserted. This would correspond to the order of the JSON string going into `json.loads`.

Comment: We are using the Python 3.7 version. Could you please confirm if the order of the dict in the Python 3.0 is the same as of Python 2.7? Since Python 2.7 will not be supported we are trying to migrate to Python 3.7.